# Is there a way to have Transcrypt export all imported symbols in a module?

Tags: javascript, python, transcrypt

I have a [medium-sized Python project](https://gitlab.com/iffyb/bezoar/) that I'm trying to Transcrypt into ES6. One portion of the project is a lot of internals, and I've stashed it away in a "private" package ([`bezoar._model`](https://gitlab.com/iffyb/bezoar/-/tree/master/bezoar/_model)). I have a roll-up Python module [`bezoar.model`](https://gitlab.com/iffyb/bezoar/-/blob/master/bezoar/model.py) that exports the front-facing components in `bezoar._model` by simply importing them. In Python, anything that is imported is implicitly exported. And I have noticed this seems (?) to be a standard practice, including some [modules provided by the standard library in CPython](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/collections/abc.py).

In ES6, the same is not true. One must explicitly `export foo from jsmodule` to re-export symbols from another module. I hand-modified the generated ES6 to replace `import foo from jsmodule` with `export foo from jsmodule` and it worked as expected.

**Is there any way to convince Transcrypt to do this for me?**

I tried using `__pragma__('js', ...)`, but it inserted the code after the import section, which wasn't (apparently) allowed by ES6.

**Example**

*`_modfoo.py`*:

```py
def foo():
    pass
```

*`rollup.py`*:

```py
from _modfoo import foo
```

*transcrypt generated `rollup.js`*:

```js
import {foo} from './_modfoo.js'
var __name__ = 'rollup'
```

*rexporting version of `rollup.js`*:

```js
export {foo} from './_modfoo.js'
var __name__ = 'rollup'
```

Answer (score 1):

Somehow I missed this from `transcrypt -h`:

```
  -xr, --xreex          re-export all imported names
```

Works as advertised.